# Issues connecting to friend's Minecraft server with hamachi

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

My friend and I have Hamachi. We're in the same network, but no matter how hard I try I am never able to join his server. All it says is:

> `io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information`

Is there any way I can fix this, so I can play with my friend on his server?

Answer (score 0):

If the host has a firewall enabled, try disabling it. This solved the problem for my friend and I, and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same exact same problem. We ended up disabling her firewall (the one with the server). she kept retrying and restarting the numbers. I typed it in and it worked more or less.